# javascript - box align and mouse position

Tags: javascript, css

I have 2 problems, please look at it and source code (I won't paste it here, because it will be not illegible) - [here](http://nur.kozacy.org/mapa_galeria.html.)
Firstly - box with info, like "Meksyk" or "Elba" is not directly under mouse. How can I change it? I tried on many ways with the same negative result.
Secondly - box shows info too early on left side and bottom. Why? What is wrong? Right and top side works well.

Greetings!

Comment: Please, be more specific. Post a bit of your code here so that people can take a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, I wouldn't bother to answer such a shabbily written question. But after reading "[Summer of love - Researching Comments](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/week-2-of-the-summer-of-love-researching-comments/)" - I changed my mind.

Here's the deal. In your `popup` script, there is an X and Y offset specifed. Modify those values to adjust the tooltip position. As for "shows info too early" - provide me with a more detailed explanation, and I may be able to help you out